# When do you use brace expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh, brace-expansion

I understand what [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) is, but I don't know how best to use it.

When do you use it?
Please teach me some convenient and remarkable examples if you have your own tip.

Comment: For the record, `{a,b}` brace expansion was first introduced in csh in the late 70s and the `{1..10}` `{001..100}` `{a-z}` variant by zsh in the early 90s, and yet more variations in ksh93 in the mid 2000s. Beside the shells you've already tagged, it's also available in fish and yash.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Brace expansion is very useful if you have long path names. I use it as a quick way to **backup a file**:

```
cp /a/really/long/path/to/some/file.txt{,.bak}
```

will copy `/a/really/long/path/to/some/file.txt` to `/a/really/long/path/to/some/file.txt.bak`

You can also use it in a **sequence**. I once did so to download lots of pages from the web:

```
wget http://domain.example/book/page{1..5}.html
```

or

```
for i in {1..100}
do
   #do something 100 times
done
```

Comment: This can be used for argument duplication as well. Say you have some program which requires a '-f' argument for every file to operate on. instead of doing `program -f file1 -f file2 -f file3`, you can do `program "-f file"{1..3}`

Comment: This is a shame. I just discovered it but do the backup thing on extra-long paths for years without knowing rhis. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick: That fails because `program` gets three words: `"-f file1" "-f file2" "-f file3"`, instead of 6: `"-f" "file1" "-f" "file2" "-f" "file3"`.

Comment: @dogbane: Using expansion for use in a `for` loop is a bit pointless, since you can write `for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))` and it is more efficient.

Answer (score 37):

Brace expansion comes very handy when creating large directory structures:

```
mkdir -p dir1/{subdir1,subdir2}/{subsubdir1,subsubdir2}
```

This will give you

```
find dir1 -type d
dir1
dir1/subdir1
dir1/subdir1/subsubdir1
dir1/subdir1/subsubdir2
dir1/subdir2
dir1/subdir2/subsubdir1
dir1/subdir2/subsubdir2
```

You could even go one step further and put brace expansion into brace expansion:

```
mkdir -p dir1/{subdir{1,2}}/{subsubdir{1,2}}
```

This will give you the same directory structure as the example above.

Comment: Nesting is nice, but your nesting example (`mkdir -p dir1/{subdir{1,2}}/{subsubdir{1,2}}`) doesn't actually serve any purpose.  You could have just done this: `mkdir -p dir1/subdir{1,2}/subsubdir{1,2}`.

Comment: @iconoclast, it does serve a purpose if you interpret `subdir1` and  `subdir2` in the non-literal sense. Replace `subdir1` with `cat` and `subdir2` with `dog` for example.

Comment: @ephsmith: if you interpret "subdir1" as standing in for "cat" and "subdir2" for "dog", then the nesting example fails, since it uses subdir{1,2}, and there is no string that you can replace "subdir" with that will make subdir{1,2} return {cat,dog}.

Answer (score 23):

I use it when I want to reduce typing:

```
geany /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
# versus
geany /path/to/file{1,2}
```

Another example:

```
wajig install libpam0g-dev libiw-dev libdb-dev
# versus
wajig install lib{pam0g,iw,db}-dev
```

Answer (score 13):

I use it to compare actual test output to desired test output during development.  If test #41 fails, it's easy to see what the difference between the test output (in file tests.output/041) and the desired output (in file tests.out/041):

```
$ diff tests.{out,output}/041
```

Answer (score 12):

Some frequent cases for me are:

For renaming:

```
mv myText.{txt,tex}
```

or

```
mv myText.tex{,.old}
```

or

```
cp myText.tex{,.backup}
```

(Although it's less messy to use version control for the last 2 tasks.)

For comparing (already mentioned):

```
diff path{1,2}/a.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several great answers here, but none of them mention when **not** to use brace expansion.  Like the other answerers, I use brace expansion on the command line quite a bit.  I also use it in my aliases and functions since I can expect a smart shell.

I do *not* use it in my shell scripts (unless there's some other reason the scripts should be bash or zsh, though in those cases, it's best to upgrade to a "real" scripting language like `perl` or `python`).  **Brace expansion is [not portable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)** since it is not in the POSIX shell standard.  Even if it works in your `/bin/sh`-[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)ed shell scripts, it will not work on systems with more stripped `/bin/sh` shells (e.g. `dash`).

In the case of a difference of a single digit, you don't need brace expansion; a character class will suffice:

Bashism:

```
diff file{1,2}
```

Portable:

```
diff file[12]
```

Comment: A difference is that `file{1,2}` will always expand to `file1 file2`, while `file[12]` expands only to existing filenames: i.e. if `file1` exists but `file2` doesn't, `file[12]` expands to `file1` only. The `[]` expansion is really a restricted version of `?` expansion (and they are called "pathname expansions").

Comment: Correct, brace expansion is not [shell globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (a.k.a. pathname expansion).  That's a good call-out that hasn't really been mentioned yet: brace expansion is better at noting unexpectedly absent paths.  You can also glob inside brace expansion.

Answer (score 2):

After splitting a very big file with

```
split -b 100m hugeFile.zip part.
```

let's suppose it splitted into 262 pieces, in other words `part.aa`,`part.ab`,`part.ac` ... `part.kb`

Your can join those pieces again by nesting **brace expansions**, like this

```
cat part.{{a..j}{a..z},k{a..b}} > hugeFile.zip
```