# Quick way to include a directory path when calling mv?

Tags: bash, rename

Often I will work out of the root of a rails directory where I find my self navigating the same path twice every time I would like to move a file:

```
mv app/views/layouts/application.html.erb app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
```

The haml is just one of may examples where I need to change the file name without modifying the directory it currently lives in and without changing directory.  Is there a way to achieve  this?

Comment: I remember seeing a question with an accepted answer nearly identical to mine.  However I cannot find it so I've answered your question for now, at least until someone stumbles across the link.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/when-do-you-use-brace-expansion

Comment: While the answers are the same, the questions are rather different.  That one is "I have a tool, but what's it good for?" and this one is "I have a problem, what tool should I use?"  It's probably worth keeping both.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
mv very/long/path/to/filename.{old,new}
```

would expand to

```
mv very/long/path/to/filename.old very/long/path/to/filename.new
```

Comment: Very useful and - for me - the most common case to use brace expansion. Thanks to this, I hardly ever use `rename`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to work in a directory, you can switch to it temporarily.

```
pushd app/views/layouts
mv application.html.erb application.html.haml
popd
```

Under Linux, you can use the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) utility (called `rename.ul` under Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives) to change a part of the file name (which can be in the directory part). `rename foo bar path/to/file` changes the first occurrence of `foo` in `path/to/file` to `bar`. If a file name doesn't contain the first string, the file is left in place.

```
rename .erb .haml app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
rename .erb .haml app/views/layouts/*.html.erb       # do several in one go
rename .erb .haml app/views/layouts/application.*    # never mind if application.js and application.html.gz also exist
```

When you have several consecutive words in a comman line that share a common stem, you can use brace expansion:

```
mv app/views/layouts/application.html.{erb,haml}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `cd` in the directory in a sub-shell:

```
(cd app/views/layouts && mv application.html.erb application.html.haml)
```

Here, the parentheses execute the commands in a new `bash` shell process.

Answer (score 3):

You can define function:

```
mv-rename () {
  mv -- "${1}" "$(dirname -- "${1}")/${2}"
}
```

Usage:

```
mv-rename app/views/layouts/application.html.erb application.html.haml
```