# How to repeat currently typed in parameter on Bash console?

Tags: bash, readline, line-editor

I was just typing something along the lines of:

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/narf.txt
```

Suddenly I realized, damn, I have to type large parts of that parameter again:

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/narf.txt foo/bar/poit/zoid/troz.txt
```

Even with tab completion, that's quite a pain. I know I can copy-paste the parameter by mouse-selecting the text and middleclicking but that is not good enough. I want to keep my hands on the keyboard.

Is there a way to copy-paste the current parameter of the line using the keyboard?

Comment: My advice doesn't answer your question, but is a small tip. As in your example, you can use next construction: `mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/{narf.txt,troz.txt}` instead ot typing/copypasting long address twice.

Comment: Slightly shorter than @Rush's solution: `mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/{narf,troz}.txt`. This works especially well if we have something like `.../zoid/this_source_file_has_to_be_patched.c{,.orig}`

Comment: @Rush Do you mind pointing it out as an answer? It may not be directly what I asked, but then again, your solution is much more to the point of what I want. It deserves a token of acceptance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I've planned ahead, I use [brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35782/quick-way-to-include-a-directory-path-when-calling-mv/35783#35783). In this case:

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/{narf,troz}.txt
```

---

Here is another approach using the default `readline` keyboard shortcuts:

- `mv foo/bar/poit/soid/narf.txt`: start
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>: `unix-word-rubout` to delete `foo/bar/poit/soid/narf.txt`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>: `yank`, space, `yank` again to get `mv foo/bar/poit/soid/narf.txt foo/bar/poit/soid/narf.txt`
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd>: `backward-kill-word` twice to delete the last `narf.txt`
- `troz.txt`: type the tail part that is different

If you spend any non-trivial amount of time using the `bash` shell, I'd recommend periodically reading through a list of the default shortcuts and picking out a few that seem useful to learn and incorporate into your routine.  [Chapter 8 of the `bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing) is a good place to start.  Knowing the shortcuts can really raise your efficiency.

Comment: Neat! In my case I had to press Alt + Backspace instead of Meta + Backspace.

Comment: @k0pernikus Yes on most keyboards, the Alt key is the Meta key.

Comment: To save retyping `.txt`, you could press Ctrl+Left (or any other shortcut that calls `backward-word`), then Left one character, then Alt+Backspace and type `troz`.

Answer (score 31):

History expansion actually works on the current command as well, using the [event designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html) `!#`. Combine this with the [word designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html) for the last argument, `$`, to get the parameter you just typed.

And you can use all the regular [modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html) over it, so if, e.g., you are renaming a file in a far-away directory, you can just type:

```
mv path/you/do/not/want/to/type/twice/oldname !#$:h/newname
```

Comment: Very useful! This works especially well with bash's `magic-space` option in inputrc to automatically expand history expansions. (I couldn't use the top-voted answer because I've set ^W to break at slashes since that's usually more useful.)

Comment: @SorenBjornstad `alt+backspace` usually already stops at word delimiters like slashes, so you needn't change how `^W` to get that functionality, you can have both delete non-word-character or whitespace delimited words

Answer (score 14):

As in your example, you can use next construction:

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/{narf.txt,troz.txt}
```

or even (as suggested [Ansgar Esztermann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14495/ansgar-esztermann)):

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/{narf,troz}.txt
```

instead ot typing/copypasting long address twice.

Comment: This is called [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Answer (score 8):

This inserts the last word of the Readline line buffer. `!#` is the current line, `:$` is the last word, and `\e^` is `history-expand-line`.

```
"\ej":"!#:$\e^"
```

This also works when you're in the middle of a word, and it doesn't require inserting a space manually, but it has the disadvantage that it overrides the kill ring:

```
"\ee":shell-backward-word
"\ei":shell-forward-word
"\ew":copy-region-as-kill
"\ej":"\ee\e \ei\ew \C-y"
```

In order to duplicate the previous whitespace-delimited word instead of a shell word, you can use `\C-w\C-y\C-y`. `\C-w` deletes a whitespace-delimited word backwards.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer. Pressing 'alt/option + j' now copies the last word.

Comment: Agree, it looks like it does the same as zsh's `copy-backward-word`. In `.bashrc` you can put `bind '"\e5":"!#:$\e^"'`

Answer (score 7):

Playing around I got this to work:

```
mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/narf.txt
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
 to store the last parameter.

Now use <kbd>↑</kbd> to get last typed in line back. Enter a space and to get the last used parameter use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

I hate provoking an error, but it gets the job done in this use case.

Comment: <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> is (it?) the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: Instead of using `mv` for the initial command and invoking an error, I use `file`. It just reports the type of file found. Then `mv Alt-. Alt-.`

Answer (score 3):

You can easy use variables:

```
a=test.csv ; cp $a $a.bak
```

Or in you case (note tab competition works for the **a** part):

```
a=foo/bar/poit/zoid/ ; mv ${a}narf.txt ${a}troz.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

#### A short interactive two step solution

1. type: `echo foo/bar/poit/zoid/narf.txt`

   This makes `foo/bar/poit/zoid/narf.txt` available for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut in bash.
2. type: `mv` and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

   You will get `mv foo/bar/poit/zoid/troz.txt foo/bar/poit/zoid/troz.txt`.
   Now you can modify the last word easily.

#### [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander)

This tool which might be (very) handy is a file manager running in the console. It gives you the possibility to copy filenames and directory paths interactively into the command line. Midnight Commander shows you therefore 2 panels (left and right), which list the contents of different directories.

A short guide:

- <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys select files in the current panel.
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between left and right panel.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> copies the currently selected file to the command line (including full path)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> opens the currently selected directory in the other panel
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> lets you see the console in full screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd> copies the path of the active panel into the console
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> copies the path of the inactive panel into the console
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is auto completion

This is by far the fastest way I found so far - after I got used to the shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

For `zsh`, I find the following keybindings helpful.

```
# Bind alt-m to insert previous word from the current line
bindkey '^[m' copy-prev-shell-word

# Bind alt-k to kill word before cursor in vi-style
bindkey '^[k' vi-backward-kill-word
```

So I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> to repeat the last argument then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> if I want to delete parts off the end of a path.

Here's a [useful reference](http://bolyai.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_14.html) to some of the behaviors you can map.

Comment: If only bash had something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Use the same thing in the {,} "duplicator". I.e.:

```
git tag -m {v,v}1.0.1

# same as 

git tag -m v1.0.1 v1.0.1
```