# How to repeat currently typed in parameter in zsh?

Tags: zsh, zle

Sometimes we just need to type a slightly different name when using `mv/cp/convert`. For example,

```
convert IMG-long-number.jpg  IMG-long-number.png
```

How can I repeat IMG-long-number.jpg before typing the IMG-long-number.png, so I only need to make small adjustment?

This is similar to [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console) but for zsh/zle.

Comment: I just tested in zsh, and the solution from the link you provided also worked in zsh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!#$<Tab>` works for me. Given:

```
$ echo a
```

Typing `!#$` then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> expands `!#$` to `a`. Tab completion also lists other options if you try an operation with `:`:

```
$ echo a !#$:
&  -- repeat substitution
A  -- absolute path resolving symbolic links
Q  -- strip quotes
a  -- absolute path
c  -- PATH search for command
e  -- leave only extension
g  -- globally apply s or &
h  -- head - strip trailing path element
l  -- lower case all words
q  -- quote to escape further substitutions
r  -- root - strip suffix
s  -- substitute string
t  -- tail - strip directories
u  -- upper case all words
```

Comment: [Why so complicated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319072)

Comment: @Gilles more flexible, though. `!#[0,1/^,...$]` all work in a similar way

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to bear in mind is that: you don't.

After using completion to get

```
convert IMG-long-number.jpg
```

simply edit that into

```
convert IMG-long-number.{jpg,png}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+_</kbd> that copies the previous word (`copy-prev-word` widget). Once copied, you can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to edit the extension of the copy.

Or use <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> to delete it as a whole. By default, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> deletes whole words (defined as alnums+$WORDCHARS), but you can change the behaviour on demand with the `select-word-style` widget.

In `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload select-word-style
zle -N select-word-style
bindkey '\eW' select-word-style
```

Then, you can select a different *word style* with <kbd>Alt+Shift+W</kbd>. You can use the `bash` word style (words only alnums) here (the reference is to how `bash` word widgets *other than <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>* like <kbd>Alt+B</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+D</kbd>... consider *words*).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the vi mode in zsh then you can just write the first number, then `ESC` and `Byt.` to copy until dot. Finally `A` and `SPC` to go to the end and insert a space and `ESC` `Pi.png` to paste and type the png extension.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @muru suggested - `!#$<TAB>`. But I also made a bindings like this in my .zshrc :

```
bindkey -s "^[," "!#\$^I"
```

That way, pressing `Esc` then comma will do it for you, similar to when `Esc` then dot will get you the last argument from the previous command.

Comment: But `zsh` already has a widget (`copy-prev-word`) and binding for that (Ctrl+Alt+_). If you'd rather have it on (Alt+,), `bindkey '\e,' copy-prev-word`

Comment: Well, technically, it is not the same. Type something like `command "parameter with spaces"` and then try yours and my solutions. Both my and yours approach could be used in different situations.

That being said, zsh has another widget `copy-prev-shell-word` that works exactly like my previous suggestion.