# How to do this: cp file1 $1.bkup?

Tags: shell

This is the goal:

```
cp file1 file1.bkup
```

I don't want to type file1 twice, what's the easiest way pls ?
in bash or or shells.

Comment: Closely related: [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Bash or some other shells, you could use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
cp file1{,.bkup}
```

This will expand to:

```
cp file1 file1.bkup
```

Comment: little bit complicated, wish there's a simpler syntax, but thx a lot !

Comment: @user3552178 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.