# cp : short way of copying

Tags: command-line, brace-expansion

I don't remember exactly but there was either `cp` or `mv` command which I was able to do something like this with:

```
cp file{.cpp, .cpp.org}
```

Which would copy `file.cpp` and make a copy named `file.cpp.org`. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick way to include a directory path when calling mv?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35782/quick-way-to-include-a-directory-path-when-calling-mv)

Comment: there is a space in braces

Comment: thanks,damphat . Space was the real problem it was not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a property of the shell, and not a property of the command itself. Check for more info: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace

On the command line,

```
file{.cpp,.cpp.org}
```

will always expand to

```
file.cpp file.cpp.org
```

In your example, it would be shorter to just type

```
file.cpp{,.org}
```