# How to copy a file within its original directory, most easily?

Tags: cp, file-copy

What I want to do is basically

```
cp long/directory/path/file long/directory/path/file-copy
```

This or similar operations are pretty common. Typing out the whole path twice is obviously awkward, even with auto-completion or copy-paste. There are a couple of simple ways to do it, but none seems ideal:

- First `cd` into the directory, then simply `cp file file-copy`. Least keystrokes, but I end up in the directory, which I didn't really want.
- Wrap the above in a subshell, `sh -c 'cd dir-path; cp file file-copy'`, to make the `cp` local. Fair enough, but that means I have to type the commands in a string literal, which disables auto-completion and isn't overall nice.
- Define the dir as a variable, then just `cp "$dir/file" "$dir/file-copy"`. Can work nicely, but I'm kind of paranoid about namespace pollution...
- `echo dir-path | while read p; do cd "$p"; cp file file-copy; done`. Basically combines subshell-wrapping with variable definition, by emulating a lambda-calculus stype let-binding with `read`. I quite like it, but it's just a bit weird, and involves a lot of extra characters.
- Anything I can come up with that uses `sed 's/file/file-copy/'` needs even more boilerplate around it.
- *Open* the file with an editor, then save-as. Not well applicable to non-text files, and often resource-costly.

Is there a more elegant alternative? Ideally one that works with `mv` as well, analogously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35782/quick-way-to-include-a-directory-path-when-calling-mv), you can use:

```
cp /long/path/to/file{,-copy}
```

This a shell expansion done by `bash` (not sure about others), so it will work with any command.

Comment: When you find a question that duplicates another question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of answering it. Use the “flag” button on the question, select “it is a duplicate”, and enter the link to the question.