# How can I rename a file in a nested path "in place," i.e. without re-typing the full path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, files, rename

I find myself frequently needing to rename different files with `mv` that are in deep directories:

```
mv /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt.bak
```

But I don't want to retype the full path name. Is there a quick shorthand or alias that I could use? I.e.:

```
$ mv /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt file.txt.bak
$ ls /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt.bak
a/long/path/to/a/file.txt.bak
```

(note: this is for straightforward, single file renames in different directories at different times, not for [mass-renames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372719/using-sed-to-mass-rename-files))

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6036/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
mv /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt{,.bak}
```

This renames `/a/long/path/to/a/file.txt` with an empty suffix to `/a/long/path/to/a/file.txt` with suffix `.bak`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice way without aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'd probably use brace expansion, as illustrated in [Freddy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586021/65304), in both `bash` and `zsh` one could use interactive *history expansion*, with designator `#$` to refer to the last word typed so far on the current line:

```
mv /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt !#$.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a basic question, but I hadn't found a existing question/answer for this. The simple solution I made was a function in `~./bash_functions`**:

```
#/home/user/.bash_functions

function mv-rn() {
  mv $1 $(dirname $1)/${2}
}
```

So that now:

```
$ mv-rn /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt file.txt.bak
$ ls /a/long/path/to/a/file.txt.bak
a/long/path/to/a/file.txt.bak
```

---

(**note that you must have this in your ~/.bashrc for the above function to be recognized as an alias):

```
# Function definitions.
if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then
    . ~/.bash_functions
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd /a/long/path/to/a && mv file.txt file.txt.bak)
```

The `&&` ensures that the mv will be executed only if the cd succeeds. The parentheses mean that the commands will execute in a subshell, so the cd will not change your existing shell's working directory.