# mv command: how to short directory location

Tags: bash, mv

I need to rename a file in a multi-nested directory, that's very long location; I'll use `mv` command.
I'd like to save time by typing only once the full location.

Is there a way to shorten the destination directory when moving a file?

I'll explain it better with an example:
`mv /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.txt /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/moved_file.txt` ---> `mv /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.txt moved_file.txt`

Comment: if you `cd` to the destination directory, you don't need to provide the full path of the destination file.

Comment: See [How can I rename a file in a nested path "in place," i.e. without re-typing the full path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586018/how-can-i-rename-a-file-in-a-nested-path-in-place-i-e-without-re-typing-the)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a programmatic method of identifying the path and the filename....

```
SRC=/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5
DEST=/dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD

mv "$SRC"/file.txt "$DEST"/moved_file.txt
```

Or, for just a rename...

```
mv "$SRC"/file.txt "$SRC"/moved_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` to change the working directory to `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5`, then call `mv`.  Do it in a sub-shell to avoid having to `cd` back to the original directory (the change of working directory is local to the `(...)` sub-shell).

```bash
( cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5 && mv file.txt moved_file.txt )
```

The `&&` additionally causes the `mv` not to be performed if the `cd` fails for whatever reason.